# How to set PATH for notepad++ in Cgywin64 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, command-line, notepad++, path

Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.

This is not about an official Ubuntu flavor. Questions about other Linux distributions can be asked on Unix & Linux, those about Windows on Super User, those about Apple products on Ask Different and generic programming questions on Stack Overflow.

Closed 2 days ago.

(Private feedback for you)

I have both notepad++ and Cgywin64 installed on Windows 10, they all run correctly, my notepad++ path on Windows is "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", and in Cgywin64 is "cgydrive/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe", I want to input "notepad++ filename", then notepad++ would open the file "filename", just as the "notepad" style - when I input "notepad filename", the editor notepad would open my file "filename", and I can edit in it.

I have tried "$ export PATH=$PATH:"/C/Program Files/Notepad++/" "and "$ export PATH=$PATH:"cgydrive/C/Program Files/Notepad++" " in Cgywin64, they all didn't work, and I could use "notepad++" in CMD of Windows 10.

How to do it? I have searched on the net, while there was no concrete solution for this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My guess is it should be `/cygdrive/c` instead of `/cygdrive/C`. (Also not that it's cyg(win), not cgy(win).)

Comment: Right, thanks for your remind, since I now could run it as I intend to, so I would not try it now.

Comment: I tried justnow, " export PATH=$PATH:"cygdrive/c/Program Files/Notepad++ " didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - Install notepad++ again under Cygwin64's bin folder, and type this line each time open Cgywin64:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:"/bin/Notepad++"
```